# JUnit Test & Integration Test - Jenkins - Cucumber

Tags: maven, unit-testing, continuous-integration, jenkins-pipeline, integration-testing

I have recently started applying Cucumber in my Project and creating the framework.
Now, what we are facing is, when we are running the test cases via Jenkins, then what we want to achieve is a method where we can call our Junit test cases separately like before the deployment and Integration Test cases separately(Cucumber Tests) like after the deployment.
How we can achieve this via Jenkins, if we use the same POM file for Cucumber tests as used for the Development?
Jenkins Pipeline
Before deployement - Trigger Junit - Deployment - after deployment - Trigger Integration Cucumber

Answer (score 0):

There is not much information that you have shared here. But here's how you can achieve it. If you are using maven, then via maven's surefire plugin you can configure to run (J)unit tests. Then do deployment either via maven or custom scripts. Then using failsafe plugins trigger your integration tests. All of these can be controlled via different maven goals / phases.